# external panels in swing

Tags: java, swing

I have something like this...
[image: Grid of panels]

Its a bunch of JLabels within JPanels inside a

--JFrame

```
--JPanel

    --Set<JPanel>
        --JLabel object contained in each JPanel object cotained in the set
```

I want to create an external panel/frame so that each time I hover over each individual JPanel, a new frame/panel pops up giving me some data. This will essentially overlap over the JFrame.

Its pretty brief but I just need some guidance as to what I need to look up.

Comment: use JTable instead, then use Renderer for coloring, highlighting, read Oracle tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just use JToolTip. When the mouse hovers over the label for a couple of seconds it will display automatically. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tool Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).

Or if you want something more complicated use a MouseListener. On `mouseEntered()` you can display a `JPopupMenu` or an undecorated `JDialog`.

You can start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this pop-up component probably shouldn't be destroyed and created each time it is needed.  Instead in the action to display the popup, reset the model to the correct popup model item, and make it visible (when done, make it invisible).

Comment: From what I briefly researched,JToolTip's API is very minimal, its not as extensive as say JPanel. JPopupMenu and JDialog don't entirely fit into what I'm trying to do.

Is it not possible to use a JFrame or a JPanel that operates outside the frame and populate it with other components?

Comment: @zam, `Is it not possible to use a JFrame or a JPanel that operates outside the frame and populate it with other components?` Did you read my answer? What other component did I suggest?

Comment: JDialog worked quite well. Your awesome, thanks. Your pretty useful on SO. I'm sure if you linked a bitcoin address, you'd have many come your way